# MySQL collation Russian and Finnish

Tags: mysql, collation, cyrillic

I want to set a db column collation as Russian and Finnish. I found that there are either Russian or Finnish collations, but no simultaneous ones.

For Russian symbols `ALTER TABLE Teams CHANGE Name CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_bin NOT NULL;`

For Finnish symbols `ALTER TABLE Teams CHANGE Name CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL;`

Is there any possibility to store both RU/FI symbols?

Comment: Correctly sorting a group of strings that are not of the same language *(and in this case, not even the same alphabet)* is not a trivial task, and databas collation will not help you. For **storing** data, use UTF-8. For **collating**, you need to figure out how to "intertwine" Finnish and Russian texts pseudo-alphabetically.

Comment: Suggest `COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` for collation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [UTF-8.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html)

It's the modern and vastly superior choice, and covers all the characters you need (and more):

> The idea of UTF-8 is that various Unicode characters are encoded
>   using byte sequences of different lengths:
>
> Basic Latin letters, digits, and punctuation signs use one byte.
>
> Most European and Middle East script letters fit into a 2-byte
>   sequence: extended Latin letters (with tilde, macron, acute, grave and
>   other accents), Cyrillic, Greek, Armenian, Hebrew, Arabic, Syriac, and
>   others.

If you are working in a PHP context, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) for advice on how to implement UTF-8.

Comment: That will just solve the issue with **storing** values. Collation is something else.

Comment: Thanks! This helped!

Comment: @AndersTornblad true. In this case the main need appears to have been storage, though.

Comment: Ah, I missed that last sentence. :)

Comment: My question would be then, what characters from any languages does it not support?